# Parsing Expiry information from AD

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I am trying to find out if a an account in Active Directory is expired or not.

At the moment I have this function:

```
public bool IsUserExpired(DirectoryEntry entry)
{
    object? expirationDateValue = entry?.InvokeGet("AccountExpirationDate");

    if (expirationDateValue != null && expirationDateValue is Int64)
    {
        long expirationDateFileTime = (Int64)expirationDateValue;
        DateTime expirationDateTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(expirationDateFileTime);
        Logger.Debug($"AD User: {entry?.Username} will expire on {expirationDateTime} ");
        return expirationDateTime < DateTime.Now;
    }

    return false; // User not found or no expiration date set
}
```

this function always returns false at the moment, so either expirationDateValue is null or it isn't Int64 or both? I have a list of DirectoryEntries and go through them in a foreach loop elsewhere.

So in the end this function is being used like this:

```
if ((userAccountControl & 0x2) != 0x2 && !IsUserExpired(memberEntry))
{
    var nMember = new LdapUser(memberEntry);
    Logger.Debug($"Adding {nMember} to LdapSubGroup {SAMAccountName}");
    Members.Add(nMember);
}
```

userAccountControl is just checking if the user is locked out or not.

Am I doing something obviously wrong???

Thanks for any clue you've got.

Comment: Did you mean `accountExpires` not `AccountExpirationDate` ?